# how to import firebase.auth to angular 10

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have been using firebase for several years, and how to import it properly has always been a mystery to me.
I have been doing this:

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
const p = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
this._angularfireauth.signInWithRedirect(p);
```

After upgrade to Angular 10, I got warnings

```
depends on firebase/app. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

I suppose it means firebase/app is a commonJS module. What can I do with it?
It seems that the alternative

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
const p = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
this._angularfireauth.signInWithRedirect(p);
```

is just as bad.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The npm package `firebase` itself is not an ECMAScript module and therefore produces the warning.

If there is no ES modulized build available for your library, or if you for some reason don't care, you can add can allow specific CommonJS dependencies in the `angular.json` file:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    // ...
    "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["firebase/app"]
  }
```

Comment: Curious why [is-esm](https://github.com/mgechev/is-esm) says that it is ECMAScript, but angular-cli display the warning

Comment: Thanks. I think this becomes an angular/fire problem instead of angular 10 issue. anguar/fire re-exports most of firebase stuff, but didn't export the auth object. As a result, callers do not have access to the auth providers without directly importing from firebase.

Comment: I wonder if this is on the docket to be fixed... although it seems like the Angular team is missing...